# JavaFX Font not being rendered correctly

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Hello");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Getting following first lines on console:

35026:1978749] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNS-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
2021-06-09 00:00:46.808 java[35026:1978749] CoreText note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSystemFontNameRequest to debug.
2021-06-09 00:00:46.815 java[35026:1978749] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNS-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
2021-06-09 00:00:46.982 java[35026:1978817] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNS-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].

OS: macOS
javafx-sdk-11.0.2
jdk 11

instead of Hello getting following text on button
[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer, just a suggestion. By default, JavaFX uses logical fonts which have mappings to physical fonts and those mappings also depend on the default [locale](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html). I don't have MacOS but you should check what physical font Java is trying to load and then check whether that font can display `Hello World!`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<strike>The issue is that you do not have the font: ".SFNS-Regular" either installed or configured correctly so that JavaFx can tell where it is</strike>. I'm actually not sure if it is because of the font not being installed/configured correctly but....

What I had to do to resolve this was to add:

```
* {
   -fx-font-family: 'serif'
}
```

in my root CSS file. If you are not using CSS files or are using inline styles, then you can still set a global font:

Instead of this:

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
```

You can do something like this:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
scene.getRoot().setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'serif'");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
```

You can read more about JavaFX fonts [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont) as well as additional CSS configurations for the components. [Using CSS files](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/javafx_css.htm) is a great way to separate the component styles from their logic and if you have created web pages before, it will feel very familiar and really easy to pick up.

Comment: It helps, thanks for the contributing!

Comment: It does work, but you have to do it for every scene. Is there a way to set this globally ?

Comment: After some research: you can set a global font by calling Application.setUserAgentStylesheet() but unfortunately you need to set the whole global stylesheet, you can't add a stylesheet to the default one.

Comment: Yeah it works but you have to do it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by switching the Module SDK back to 11.0.8. You can find that [here on the Java SE 11 Archive Downloads page.](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html)

Seems that this is isolated to 11.0.12.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adjusting the JDK version and I was also using macOS and JDK 11. Although I did not have JDK 8, JDK 14 worked fine and JDK 17 did not. It will work fine if you change the project structure to a more compatible JDK version with JavaFx.

Answer (score 0):

Using another version of JDK11 fixed this for me:

> JDK 11.0.15, AdoptOpenJDK(HotSpot)

Answer (score -5):

How can one correct the same issue in a "fxml."

```
<font>
    <Font name="Times New Roman bold" size="20"/>
    </font>
```

in other words, What would replaced in <Font...."20"/> to make the same correction.
Thanks
kinda new at this

Comment: Is that a question or the answer?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I'm guessing your answer is a question and the answer to your question is: [FXML Label text bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813907/fxml-label-text-bold)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.